# Flask virtualenv - do we need to call `sudo` when install via `pip` in Ubuntu?

Tags: flask, virtualenv

### Context

OS to be Ubuntu Desktop

Python & Flask to be [installed in virtual environment](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/installation/)

### My need

Install more Python packages to use in my Flask application.

### My question

Do we need to call sudo when install via `pip install` command?

Comment: Did you try to install with `sudo`? Did you try to install without it? Did you try the commands on the page you linked to?

Comment: I tried both. And both succeeded. So, I just wonder and ask here.

Comment: When given the choice between installing something with or without root access, it's almost always better to install it without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes both do work. The difference is that `pip install` installs the package in the current virtual environment while `sudo pip install` installs a package for the global system wide python installation meaning you can access that package outside the virtual environment.

Comment: Note that installing the package in the global system is bad in the sense that it makes the virtual env meaningless. If you use a virtualenv install all needed packages into it and not globally.